# why does my listView is set to default images only?

Tags: java, android, listview, caching, android-listview

I have an android listView which I fill with images.

I load the list from the server by silent paging.

I use async download task to download the images and a cache layer to persist them.

Whenever my adapter execute getView it sets the image tag to be its url.

Then before I load the drawable to the image view, I check it's still relevant (as it's async task and the scroll might move already and the item has been recycled by then) by comparing the downloaded url to the url kept in the tag.

However I see only the default image is seen usually,

What is missing in my logic?

```
private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> imageCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(
        100);

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (position != 0
                && (PublicMacros.OFFERS_PAGE_SIZE / 2 == position)
                && ((position / PublicMacros.OFFERS_PAGE_SIZE + 1)
                        * PublicMacros.OFFERS_PAGE_SIZE + 1) > mOffersList
                            .size() && lastTriggeringPosition != position)
        // ask next page
        // maybe add loader
        {
            lastTriggeringPosition = position;
            mOffersListActivity.getOffersFromServer(++pageNumber,
                    PublicMacros.OFFERS_PAGE_SIZE);
        }
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mOffersListActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_list_item, null);
        } else {
            // fetch existing data
        }

        initLayout(position, convertView);


        setChangeableViews(convertView);

        return convertView;


    }


//called in setChangeableViews
    private void setItemBgImage(View convertView) {
        String imageUrl = getImageUrlFromOffer(convertView);
        Bitmap bitmap = imageCache.get(imageUrl);

        // anyhow set to default image
        Drawable dr = mOffersListActivity.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.lock_closed);
        ImageView offerImage = ((ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.offerImage));
        if (bitmap != null) {
            dr = new BitmapDrawable(
            // bitmap compression code
                    mOffersListActivity.getResources(), bitmap);
        } else {

            // check if already in the process of downloading
            if (!downloadingImageUrls.contains(imageUrl)) {
                downloadingImageUrls.add(imageUrl);
                new DownloadImageAsyncTask2(offerImage).execute(imageUrl);
            }
        }
        offerImage.setImageDrawable(dr);
        offerImage.setTag(imageUrl);
    }




public class DownloadImageAsyncTask2 extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final ImageView imageView;
        private String imageUrl;

        public DownloadImageAsyncTask2(ImageView imageView) {
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("DownloadImageAsyncTask", "Starting image download task...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            imageUrl = params[0];
            try {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                        imageUrl).getContent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("DownloadImageAsyncTask", "Error reading bitmap" + e);
                downloadingImageUrls.remove(imageUrl);
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. Please specify imageCache, I assume it is hashmap of imageurl and Bitmap. You should be putting the values of bitmap to imageCache hashmap in you onPostExecute() and may be removing from downloading list.

Comment: thanks, I have added the `imageCache`

Comment: Override the onPostExecute as mentioned above in the comments.

Comment: it worked! thanks. But now loading is really slow. Should I open a new question regarding how to improve loading time?

Comment: Cool !!. Loading may be slow due to high size bitmaps. Try to improve user code for performance now.

Comment: I'm not sure how. do you have any example? I have tried this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192193/why-does-my-listview-is-set-to-default-images-only?noredirect=1#comment39255171_25192193

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this library.

It's a library for loading, caching and displaying images on Android.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader